# Rails ActiveRecord 4: correct way to write a greater than

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I know that

```
Object.where('key > ?', value)
```

works.

But if the query happens to have several tables involved, with multiple `key` columns, it *might* break as the query produced is:

```
SELECT "tablename".* FROM "tablename"  WHERE "tablename"."user_id" = $1 AND (key > 0)  [["user_id", 29]]
```

A solution would be

```
Object.where('tablename.key > ?', value)
```

But ain't there an arel way to write this instead? My app has (enforced) weird table names, I'd rather not write them there and that they get added dynamically by active record.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd personally still try to stay with AR on that one, and do something with a range and a hash query:

```
Object.where(tablename: { key: value..Float::INFINITY}) # If value is a number
Object.where(tablename: { key: value..DateTime::Infinity.new}) # If value is a DateTime
```

Comment: I don't see any *greater than* condition there.

Comment: `key > 30` is equivalent to `key is between 30 and infinity`, hence the range above.

Comment: Gotcha! Didn't see the `..` Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit verbose, but you can use [arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) to do this. For example

```
Object.where(Object.arel_table[:key].gt(123))
```

will select objects where `key > 123`.

If I was doing this, I would probably define some helper methods, perhaps something along the lines of

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.column(name)
    Foo.arel_table[name]
  end
  #now you can do
  def self.some_method
    Foo.where(column(:key).gt(123))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're querying from one object (one table) you can drop the table name in the where clause.

```
Object.where('key > ?', value)
```

Unfortunately that's the best way there is to do it.